# Why is asset:precompile failing on Rails 6.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, yarnpkg, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I have an image asset in app/assets/images which I am trying to compile before deploying in production as per [asset pipeline guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Upon trying to execute:

```
 RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile
```

I get the following error:

```
rails aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - C:/../bin/yarn --version

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile => yarn:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The above error also happens when I run

```
rails yarn:install
```

Checking yarn version

```
$ yarn
yarn install v1.22.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.80s.
```

I have installed webpacker 5.2. I tried to check the bin/yarn file but did not find any problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem, and this deals because using rails 6.1 that has [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/40795), they have pushed merge to branch, but if you still has problem

temporary solution that I did

create one file /bin/yarn
if you using linux just put content as below

```
#!/bin/bash

exit 0
```

and make sure it executable, by running chmod 755 /bin/yarn
now you can run precompile command